# Unable to cast to button

Tags: c#

I am getting this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe Additional information: Unable to cast
>   object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser'.

Heres the code

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt");

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            textBox6.Text = "";
            textBox5.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";

            textBox6.Text = counter.ToString();
            string link = line.ToString() ;
            textBox5.Text = link;
         //   WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(link);
         //   req.Method = "GET";


            WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
            wb.Navigate(link);
            wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);

            wb.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);

            string html = wb.DocumentText;
            textBox1.Text = html;
            textBox2.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
            textBox3.Text = "done";

            if (html.Contains("<title>"))
            {
                string title = ExtractFromString(html, "<title>", "</title>");
                textBox4.Text = title;
            }
            else
            {
                string title = ExtractFromString(html, "<TITLE>", "</TITLE>");
                textBox4.Text = title;
            }

            wb.Dispose();
            createpage(textBox4.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox5.Text);


            counter++;
        }
        file.Close();
        textBox3.Text = counter.ToString();


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The event handler is raised by a button. You try to cast it to a WebBrowser. It obviously can't work. Try to fix WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender; to assign something right to wb.

Answer (score 2):

The `sender` is almost certainly a `Button` (from the function name "button6_click").

```
WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
```

`Button` cannot be cast to `WebBrowser` (for hopefully obvious reasons). You will likely need to reference the `WebBrowser` control by name in this case.

```
WebBrowser wb = someExistingNamedWebBrowser;
```

Comment: I have just done this, the loop just goes through the loop without ever doing navigate link or the document complete :s

Comment: @AdamMoore Then you have an empty file or some other problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this line:

```
WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
```

Because this is in a button click event, the `sender` will be a `Button`. Try this:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
```

Or if you have one already on your form, reference it:

```
WebBrowser wb = webBrowser1;
```

Comment: if I use webbrowser without sender I get this
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Unable to get the window handle for the 'WebBrowser' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported.

Comment: You are running into an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Describe, specifically, what it is you're trying to do.